# To append the attribute name with an input variable

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to append the node attribute name with an input integer value.

Eg:

```
count=1
node["example_#{count}"]
```

expected value: node[example_1]

But we are getting a nil value. Please let us know the right way of appending.

Comment: This code doesn't do anything useful in chef, please extend to explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to use it as a loop, for installing multiple packages through packer , instead of doing it sequentially. Is there any better way?

Comment: Chef support installing multiple packages with the package  resources directly. So this is a XY problem, you're asking how to implement your solution to the problem instead of asking about the problem itself. What about and [edit] to expose your real problem and keeping the loop approach as what you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a different between [setting and attribute, and retrieving an attribute](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html).

in the snippet you shared, a node attribute is being retrieved but not assign to any other variable.

if you would like to assign a value to a node attribute, do it as follows:

```rb
count = 1
node.default["example_#{count}"] = 'foo'
```